# Ordering bars in ggplot with data from two two data sets

Tags: r, ggplot2

So i have data in two separate excel sheets (CSV files) that i am inputting into R. The data in one sheet is plotted as bars and the data in the other sheet is plotted as dots. How can i make it so i can dictate the order of all the data samples on the x axis. I used this code to order the bars:

```
data7$Virus.hpi <- factor(data7$Virus.hpi, levels = c("BTV-8 0hpsi", "BTV-8 72hpsi", "BTV-1 0hpsi", "BTV-1 72hpsi"))

 ggplot(data=data7, aes(x = data7$Virus.hpi, y=ct, fill=Virus.hpi)) + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("BTV-8 0hpsi" = "purple", "BTV-8 72hpsi" = "purple", "BTV-1 0hpsi" = "blue", "BTV-1 72hpsi" = "blue")) + 
stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar") + 
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.3) +
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40, 10), labels = rev(seq(0, 40, 10)))
```

Which gave a bar chart with the bars in the order i wanted them, however when i added in my code for the dot plot the bars reverted back to the orginal order.

This was the code with the dot plot:

```
data4$Virus.hpi <- factor(data4$Virus.hpi, levels = c("BTV-8 0hpi", "BTV-8 72hpi", "BTV-1 0hpi", "BTV-1 72hpi"))

ggplot(data=data7, aes(x = data7$Virus.hpi, y=ct, fill=Virus.hpi)) + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("BTV-8 0hpsi" = "purple", "BTV-8 72hpsi" = "purple", "BTV-1 0hpsi" = "blue", "BTV-1 72hpsi" = "blue")) + 
stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar") + 
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.3) + 
geom_point(data=data4, aes(x = data4$Virus.hpi, y=ct, fill=Virus.hpi)) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40, 10), labels = rev(seq(0, 40, 10)))
```

Thanks

dput(data7)

```
structure(list(Virus.hpi = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("BTV-8 0hpsi", "BTV-8 72hpsi", "BTV-1 0hpsi", 
"BTV-1 72hpsi"), class = "factor"), X = c(30.78, 29.15, 30.07, 
30.03, 28.77, 29.8, 24.59, 25.86, 28.69, 23.88, 23.07, 26.7, 
25.26, 16.07, 24.31, 23.86, 23.08, 23.8, 13.07, 15.67, 17.54, 
16.79, 17.23, 15.41), ct = c(9.22, 10.85, 9.93, 9.97, 11.23, 
10.2, 15.41, 14.14, 11.31, 16.12, 16.93, 13.3, 14.74, 23.93, 
15.69, 16.14, 16.92, 16.2, 26.93, 24.33, 22.46, 23.21, 22.77, 
24.59)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

dput(data4)

```
structure(list(Virus.hpi = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("BTV-8 0hpi", "BTV-8 72hpi", 
"BTV-1 0hpi", "BTV-1 72hpi"), class = "factor"), X = c(32.11, 
33.12, 32.2, 14.87, 17.65, 21.5, 29.33, 30.33, 29.7, 16.42, 17.9, 
14.6), ct = c(7.89, 6.88, 7.8, 25.13, 22.35, 18.5, 10.67, 9.67, 
10.3, 23.58, 22.1, 25.4)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you able to edit your question to share your data using `dput(data4)` and `dput(data7)`?

Comment: But you should avoid doing `aes(x = data7$Virus.hpi` - just use `aes(x = Virus.hpi`. And you don't need an `aes` call at all inside `geom_point`, since the mapping will be inherited from your original `ggplot` call, even though the data is in another data frame.

Comment: I have added the datasets i am using

Comment: You didn't add the datasets you are using. These are _pictures_ of your data sets. These cannot be used to test or verify possible solutions. No one is going to sit and transcribe your images into text. You can easily convert them to text with `dput(data4)` and `dput(data7)` as suggested previously. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know about dput, hopefully this is now more useful

Comment: Thanks Rhiannon. With reproducible data, it was straightforward to fix - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the factor levels in `data4` are different from those in `data7`. In `data7`, the labels all have an extra "s" in them, for example the first level in `data7` is "BTV-8 0hp**s**i", whereas in `data4` it is "BTV-8 0hpi". `ggplot` is putting all of these 8 levels in the x axis, and since it has had to combine two vectors of factor levels, it has had to default to alphabetical order.

One possible solution is to simply remove the "s" in the labels of `data7`

```r
data7$Virus.hpi <- sub("s", "", as.character(data7$Virus.hpi))
data7$Virus.hpi <- factor(data7$Virus.hpi, levels = levels(data4$Virus.hpi))
```

Now the plot retains the specified colors

```
ggplot(data7, aes(Virus.hpi, ct, fill = Virus.hpi)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("BTV-8 0hpi" = "purple", "BTV-8 72hpi" = "purple", 
                             "BTV-1 0hpi" = "blue", "BTV-1 72hpi" = "blue")) + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.3) +
  geom_point(data = data4) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40, 10), labels = rev(seq(0, 40, 10)))
```

[image]